# Creating pagination component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to create pagination component. For e.g if my API returns `"pages": 9`

For example, if I have 9 pages, I want to cut the list at 5 and add three dots like on the image. I want to be able to provide at which index I can cut the list. Whats the best way to do this? I am approaching this wrong?

[image]

```html
<div v-for="index in pages" class="flex">
<button>{{index}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: **vue2** or **vue3**?

Comment: @User10519069 vue 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you receive `cutIndex` and `apiPages` as props to your component, then your template could look something like the following:

```html
<div v-for="page in Math.min(cutIndex, apiPages)" class="flex">
  <button>{{page}}</button>
</div>
<template v-if="cutIndex < apiPages">
  <div class="flex">
    <button>...</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <button>{{apiPages}}</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me, and here is the key part

```js
<template>
        ...
        <template v-for="index in pages"
            v-if="(index < 4 || (length - index) < 3) || Math.abs(index - value) < 2">
            <span v-if="index === (length - 2) && value < (length - 4)">
                ...
            </span>
            <button @click.prevent="updatePage(index)">
                {{ index }}
            </button>
            <span v-if="(index === 3 && value > 5)">
                ...
            </span>
        </template>
        ...
</template>
```

the result:

[image]

```js
<template>
    <nav class="flex items-center justify-center" role="pagination">
        <!-- go to previous page -->
        <a :key="`${$route.name}-arrow-${value > 1 ? value - 1 : 1}`"
            :href="getFullPath(value > 1 ? value - 1 : 1)"
            :title="$t('previous_page')"
            @click.prevent="updatePage(value > 1 ? value - 1 : 1)"
            :disabled="value === 1"
            class="arrow pop-btn default rounded-sm"
            v-waves>
            <i class="mdi-chevron-left mdi"></i>
        </a>

        <template v-for="index in length"
            v-if="(index < 4 || (length - index) < 3) || Math.abs(index - value) < 2">
            <span v-if="index === (length - 2) && value < (length - 4)">
                ...
            </span>
            <a :href="getFullPath(index)"
                :title="$t('page_index', {index: index})"
                @click.prevent="updatePage(index)"
                class="pop-btn number default rounded-sm"
                :class="{
                    'active': index === value
                }"
                v-waves>
                {{ index }}
            </a>
            <span v-if="(index === 3 && value > 5)">
                ...
            </span>
        </template>

        <!-- go to next page -->
        <a :href="getFullPath(value === length ? value : value + 1)"
            :title="$t('next_page')"
            @click.prevent="updatePage(value === length ? value : value + 1)"
            :disabled="value === length"
            class="arrow pop-btn default rounded-sm"
            v-waves>
            <i class="mdi-chevron-right mdi"></i>
        </a>

    </nav>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
export default{
    emits: ['update:value],
    props: {
        length: {
            required: true,
            type: Number
        },
        // the page filter
        value: {
            required: true,
            type: Number
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updatePage(index){
            this.$emit('update:value', index);
        },
        getFullPath(page){
            let query = {...this.$route.query};
            page === 1 ? delete query.page : query.page = page;
            return this.$router.resolve(
                this.r({
                    query: query,
                    name: this.$route.name,
                    params: this.$route.params
                })
            ).href;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

by the way, `<a>` may better than `<button>` for SEO

Comment: Just a note on `v-for` and `v-if`, it is not recommended to use them on the same element - https://v3.vuejs.org/style-guide/#avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential

Comment: thanks a lot! I just copy them from my old project which is coded in nuxt 